# In MFC, how can WinMain function find user application object's address value?

Tags: c++, mfc

Greeting, I'm novice in MFC area.

I have a question about process of starting MFC application.

I learned that unlike SDK program, I don't have to write **WinMain**. Because It is supplied by the class library and is called when the application starts up.*
(See reference here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdx0603.aspx)

And my curious part is here: *Then CWinApp calls **member functions of the application object** to initialize and run the application.

That sentence indicates that CWinApp already know address value of application object which is made by a programmer.

However, even though application object is defined as global variable, how can WinMain function find application object's address value?

I couldn't find any connection or declaration in my sample MFC code which brings address value to the WinMain function.

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class CHelloApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};

class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
CMainFrame();
protected:
afx_msg void OnPaint();
afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
CHelloApp theApp;

BOOL CHelloApp::InitInstance()
{
m_pMainWnd = new CMainFrame;
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
return TRUE;
}

CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
Create(NULL, "HelloMFC Application");
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: MFC knows CWinApp, the InitInstance() function is virtual for a good reason.

Comment: *appmodul.cpp* implements `_tWinMain`, that simply calls `AfxWinMain` (defined in *winmain.cpp*). The pointer to the global `CWinApp`-derived object is stored in process-local storage, and is accessible from anywhere calling [AfxGetApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9f064x.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but now I want to know how AfxGetApp function works. Googling on that function makes me more confused...

Comment: You have full source code available for `AfxGetApp()` (see *afxstate.cpp*). Navigating through MFC code is easiest when loading a solution of an MFC project into Visual Studio. You get syntax highlighting and navigation aids (*"Go to definition..."*, etc.).

Comment: First of all, learn to indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, but you could answer it yourself when running your exe under a debugger, setting breakpoints at the right places and stepping into MFC source code.

The CRT provides a function `mainCRTStartup`. This function is the entry point that gets called when your program starts. `mainCRTStartup` calls `__tmainCRTStartup`. This function first calls `_initterm` to call the constructors for all global objects - like your `CWinApp theApp`. That constructor also calls `CWinApp::CWinApp` which stores the `this` pointer in a global state variable. When that is done `__tmainCRTStartup` calls `WinMain` which calls `AfxWinMain`. `AfxWinMain` is reading out the pointer to `CWinApp theApp` from the global state variable and calls the `CWinApp`'s virtual member functions.

This only works because...

- the constructor stored the `this` pointer
- only one `CWinApp` object exists
- `CWinApp` is used as an interface and thus the MFC does not need to know how exactly your `CWinApp` derived class looks like